# Using JavaScript to force all my site collections' logos to reference the root site collection is only working on IE

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery, master-page, script

I am working on a SharePoint Server 2013 and I have 4 site collections.

I want to always redirect users to the root site collection if they click on the sites logo from the 4 site collections, so I wrote the following script and added it inside the 4 site collections' master pages:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a.ms-siteicon-a").prop("href", "/");
    $("DeltaSiteLogo a.ms-siteicon-a").prop("onclick", "");
});
```

The above workes well in IE (I am using IE11) but in Firefox and Chrome the site logos' url will not reference the root site collection, and will keep referencing each site collection root site.

Can anyone advice on this please?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to miss a `#` on your second line of jQuery, change as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").prop("href", "/");
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").prop("onclick", "");
});
```

or set it in a one-line

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").prop("href", "/").prop("onclick", "");
});
```

If that does not work it may be a timing issue, try wrapping it as below:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext', function(){
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").prop("href", "/").prop("onclick", "");
});
```

Comment: Doesn't that suitebar load async? (maybe not on SP2013)

Comment: @Robert ok will try these approaches.. but why my original code is working well only on IE ,, while these are supose to work well on all browsers venders ?? i mean is there a reason ?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman the logo is not in the suitebar, it is in the title area. But it is in a DeltaPlaceHolder, so there will possibly be an MDS problem

Comment: @johnG, browsers behave differently, IE is slow as ***, different browsers trigger the DOMContentLoaded event (that `jQuery(document).ready` listens for at different times

Comment: tested it (in Chrome)... ``DeltaSiteLogo A`` is there when the DOMContentLoaded event fires, its the other stuff in the suitebar that comes in async.. sidenote.. the ``.ms-siteicon-a`` part in the selector is not required... there only is one A tag inside ``DeltaSiteLogo``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman great, I have updated the selector

Comment: While we're at it, (in SPO) there is no onclick event on the attribute, so setting it to an empty string.......

Comment: @RobertLindgren now i tried this `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").prop("href", "/").prop("onclick", "");
});`  but it did not solve the problem on chrome & firefox .. also when  i try this `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js','SP.ClientContext', function(){
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").prop("href", "/").prop("onclick", "");
});` also it did not solve the problem and even on IE the site logo url will not work ?? btw do i need to wrap the last script inside a  `$(document).ready( `

Comment: @RobertLindgren btw i am placing the script `changeLogoURL`  inside my master page after the `<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />` as follow :- `<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jquery-1.11.3.js" ></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/changeLogoURL.js" ></script>`

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best approach but why dont you try building the root site collection url

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var rootSite=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host
   $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").attr("href", rootSite)        
});
```

Comment: your appraoch looks promising .. but i am note sure if "rootSite=window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host" is suppose to work as is !! and should it be inside the $(document).ready ??

Comment: now your script will work on firefox + IE but not inside chrome..now i did my test by hard-coding the server root url as follow `$("#DeltaSiteLogo a").attr("href", "http://servername/")`..

Comment: even when you hard code your url chrome doesn't take you to the root site?

Comment: unfortunately the answer is yes...

Answer (score 0):

Try it as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#DeltaSiteLogo a").attr("href", "/")        
});
```

Comment: ,, ok will try this .. but why this should work while my original code did not ? as both have valid logic ,, is this correct?

Comment: your script did not solve the problem on firefox & chrome

Comment: Thats strange , what version of jquery are you using ? I suggest adding this code at the bottom of the master page just before `</body>` tag. Its working fine at my end using `jquery-1.12.4.min.js`

Comment: i am using jquery 1.11.3.. and i am placing the scripts after the `<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />` inside my master pages as follow:- `<SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/jquery-1.11.3.js" ></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript" src="/resources/changeLogoURL.js" ></script>` ??

Comment: ok can you move the `<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/changeLogoURL.js" ></script>` to the bottom of the master page just above the `</body>` and check ? jquery version is fine

Comment: i move it at the end of the master page but still can not get this to work on chrome and firefox

Comment: Any errors in console ? Press f12 and check the console in chrome ? Is MDS (minimal download strategy feature )enabled ?

Comment: no errors . but i think the problem is somehow related to the order the scripts get executed.. as when the pages is loading the logo url will be referencing the root ,, but when the page fully loaded the url will be referencing the current site collection